# Google App Scrtipt | Calendar API - Invalid conference type value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

So my script - which always worked now broke with the following Error message when trying to insert event to a calendar:

> Beim API-Aufruf von "calendar.events.insert" ist dieser Fehler aufgetreten: Invalid conference type value.

That means that the conferenceTypeValue isnt correct. Here is the json for the calendar event:

```
"conferenceData": {
      "createRequest": {
        "conferenceSolutionKey": { "type": "eventNamedHangout" },
        "requestId": Utilities.getUuid()
      }
}
```

Is that a problem with the API? Because in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) it is a right value.

Comment: try converting Utilities.getUuid() to a string

Comment: Thanks, but didnt work

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? I used the same parameters for `conferenceData` and it worked as expected.