# Create Event with Meet (Invalid conference type value)

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to implement Google Calendar API to create events with Meet link. So, when send request to create Event return this error from Google API: ***Error at createEvent --> Error: Invalid conference type value***

**Implemented with Service Account.**

I read many times the Google API docs, but I don't understand why this happens.

implements in NodeJS (v12.14.0), Typescript, using googleapis (Google APIs Node.js Client - "googleapis": "^67.0.0") from npm.

SCOPES:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute

```
    this.auth = new google.auth.JWT(
        this.client_email,
        null,
        this.private_key,
        environment.SCOPES
    );
```

Create Calendar

```
    async create(calendarDto: CalendarDto) {
    try {
        // let calendar = this.setCreateCalendar(calendarDto);
        let response = await this.calendar.calendars.insert({
            auth: this.auth,
            requestBody: {
                summary: calendarDto.summary,
                description: calendarDto.description,
                location: calendarDto.location,
                timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo",
                conferenceProperties: {
                    allowedConferenceSolutionTypes: ["hangoutsMeet"]
                }
            }
        });

        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error at createCalendar --> ${error}`);
        return `Error at createCalendar --> ${error}`;
    }
}
```

Create Event

```
    async createEvent(calendarId: string, createEventDto: EventDto) {
    try {
        let accessCode = this.getRandomId();
        // let event = this.setCreateEvent(createEventDto);
        let response = await this.calendar.events.insert({
            auth: this.auth,
            calendarId: calendarId,
            conferenceDataVersion: 1,
            sendNotifications: true,
            requestBody: {
                conferenceData: {
                    createRequest: {
                        requestId: this.getRandomId(),
                        conferenceSolutionKey: {
                            type: 'hangoutsMeet'
                        }
                    },
                    entryPoints: [{
                        entryPointType: 'video',
                        accessCode: accessCode,
                        meetingCode: accessCode,
                        passcode: accessCode,
                        password: accessCode,
                        pin: accessCode
                    }]
                },
                summary: createEventDto.summary,
                location: createEventDto.location,
                description: createEventDto.description,
                start: {
                    dateTime: createEventDto.startDate,
                    timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"
                },
                end: {
                    dateTime: createEventDto.endDate,
                    timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"
                },
                recurrence: [
                    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
                ],
                reminders: {
                    useDefault: false,
                    overrides: [
                        { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
                        { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 }
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error at createEvent --> ${error}`);
        return `Error at createEvent --> ${error}`;
    }
}
```

In moment test without Attendees.

Comment: Did you try other conference types?

Comment: Yes! "eventHangout", "eventNamedHangout" and "hangoutsMeet"...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: It could be an issue with the random Id you are passing. Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59769386/4243927

Comment: No! I didn't found a solution yet

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Can you retrieve that calendar via [calendars.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) in order to double-check that `hangoutsMeet` is included in `allowedConferenceSolutionTypes`?

Comment: I create the calendar with `conferenceProperties: {allowedConferenceSolutionTypes: ["hangoutsMeet"]}`. But when i run get calendar by ID don't display allowed ConferenceSolutionTypes

Comment: What type of Calendar is this? How was this created?